# react-navigation passing function as props to custom header component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I used `react-navigation` 4 in my react native app. I want to use my custom header component for my screen header. My navigator is like this:

```
const MapTab = createStackNavigator({
  MapContainer: {
    screen: MapContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: props => 
        <HeaderMap openDrawer={props.navigation.getParam('openDrawer')} />,
    },
  },
});
```

As we can see, I need to pass `openDrawer` function to my `<HeaderMap>` to open the screen drawer when it pressed. And in my screen, I've set `openDrawer` function body as navigation param on `didMount` event.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ openDrawer: this.drawer.openDrawer.bind(this) });
}
```

And I call it on `HeaderMap` as below:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.openDrawer()}>
   <Icon name="ios-menu" color={colors.white} size={30} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I always get error like this on button pressed:
`Cannot read property 'getParam' of undefined`. I think the `props.navigation` is `undefined` when I call `getParam`.

Any insight of this case? TiA.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the same code as follow:

```
const MyNavigator = createStackNavigator({


'My Pharmacy': {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: props => 
        <HeaderComp value={props} />,
    },

  },
```

The HeaderComp is:

```
    class HeaderComp extends Component{
      componentDidMount(){
      console.log('header props are: ',this.props)
    }

    render(){
      return(
        null
        )
      }
    }
```

After consoling the props I have get the navigation object.

[image]
So your props are working fine but there is something wrong in setting params. If you passed the data from outside this stack then you have to pass it through screenProps. Otherwise if you set params inside 'MapContainer' screen then there is no need to do that cause header component already get it. Try it and if still getting the same problem please add some more detail in question about from where you pass the params and where to get it.

Comment: Yes, I setParams only inside MapContainer screen and should be received by the header of that screen too. So the params scope is still in that stack for sure.

Comment: I just checked it again and the navigation is exist in the props, but getParam('...') returns nothing.

Comment: Try to pass the params like ({openDrawer:this.drawer.openDrawer})

Comment: Also try to add some temporary data in setParam and try to get it in header. Check if it works or not??

Comment: I've already solved this problem by moving the navigationOptions setting to static variable in the screen, like this way:   
`class Screen extends Component {    
    static navigationOptions: {
      header: props => 
        <HeaderComp value={props} />,
    },
}     `

Comment: Okay. Static is also one of the solution to it.

Comment: Help me with this issue if you can? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606346/react-navigation-v5-pass-function-as-parameter-to-be-used-in-headerright-butto